# Working Directory not configuring Visual Studio 2019

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a django site and I have created django project inside an **app folder of the root directory**.

My folder structure looks like [this](https://pasteboard.co/JsfcJKO.png)

```
.
├── .gitignore
├── .travis.yml
├── .vs
│   ├── PythonSettings.json
│   ├── VSWorkspaceState.json
│   ├── launch.vs.json
│   ├── recipe-app-api
│   │   └── v16
│   │       └── .suo
│   └── slnx.sqlite
├── Dockerfile
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── calc.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   ├── tests.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   │   └── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── calc.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   └── manage.py
├── docker-compose.yml
└── requirements.txt
```

I have configured my `launch.vs.json` file like this

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "python",
      "interpreter": "(default)",
      "interpreterArguments": "",
      "scriptArguments": "",
      "env": {},
      "nativeDebug": false,
      "webBrowserUrl": "",
      "project": "app\\manage.py",
      "name": "manage.py",
      "workingDirectory": "app"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem still is that *Visual Studio 2019* cannot detect that my `working directory` is the `app` folder. That's why it showing the python `import` is **unresolved**.
Image of the error [here](https://pasteboard.co/JsfhOKI.png)

Am I doing something wrong in the launch.vs.json file? How can I solve this?

*I am using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019.*

*My reputation is <10 so I cannot upload the image. Sorry for the inconvinience.*